# JS module pattern: why assignment in extending?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I see a lot of code [here](http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern), [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth):

```
var module = (function (module) {
    module.prototype.something_else = function () {
    };
    return module;
})(module);
```

Why `var module =` part present at all? And why `return module;` if previous part is not needed?

I see usage of:

```
var module = (function(module) {...})(module || {});
```

for cases when `module` wasn't already defined sometimes... Is that above case?

Comment: in case you want to extend a module?

Comment: yea, that piece is for those purpose, but some part seems redundant for me.

Comment: well...`return module` is needed , otherwise you wont expose the module... remember also , that javascript is function scoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block of code is only used if module is already defined and you want to extend it (e.g., add a new method):

```
var module = (function (module) {
    module.prototype.something_else = function () {
    };
    return module;
})(module);
```

It accepts `module` as an input parameter and returns the extended `module`. The assignment of `var module =` then replaces the original `module`.

Answering your questions one by one:

> Why var module = part present at all?

In the example above (taken from your first URL), `var module =` is not necessary. The simple example they provide is silly. You could accomplish the exact same thing with this:

```
module.prototype.something_else = function () {};
```

Using the above pattern to extend a class makes more sense with the examples provided in your second URL ( http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html ):

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    var old_moduleMethod = my.moduleMethod;

    my.moduleMethod = function () {
        // method override, has access to old through old_moduleMethod...
    };

    return my;
}(MODULE));
```

Immediate executing function creates a new scope where we can preserve the old method `var old_moduleMethod = my.moduleMethod;`

Next question:

> And why return module; if previous part is not needed?

You need `return module` because otherwise the function wouldn't return anything and the `var module =` assignment would be set to an undefined value.

Next question:

> for cases when module wasn't already defined sometimes... Is that above case?

Yes, that is the case. If `module` isn't defined then you would need to pass in an empty object. However, you typically would use a pattern to extend an object if it isn't defined in the first place. That would make no sense and would just complicate your code.

Comment: *assignment of "var module =" then replaces the original module* - I think that `module` point to same address in memory before assignment and after. Am I right? That's why I frustrated... Like `var a = a;`

Comment: You are correct, it does point to the same place in memory. Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. That's why the particular example of extensibility from the first URL is silly. They might as well just set `module.prototype.something_else = function () {};`. I updated my answer a moment ago. The example provided in your second URL provides a clear use case where using the immediate executing function to extend the object has benefits. In that example, we are able to preserve the old method.

Comment: I updated my answer slightly. You are correct `var module =` is not necessary in the example provided in the first URL.

Answer (score 1):

To understand, it helps to rename identifiers to get the equivalent

```
var module = (function (module_impl) {
    module_impl.prototype.something_else = function () {
    };
    return module_impl;
})(module || {});
```

`module_impl` is the object that is to hold the module's public API. So after populating it, the anonymous function returns it to the caller, which assigns it to the global `module`. This way the API is now available using `module` while any implementation details are hidden in the closure created by the anonymous function.

`module || {}` now is to allow augmentation: the first time it gets called, `module` is still `undefined` since the assignment to the return value of the anonymous function has not happened yet. Thus `module || {} evaluates to the second operand.

**To further illustrate why the assignment is needed.** The first time, the stub gets called, it is effectively the same as

```
var module = (function () {
    var module_impl = {};
     // ...
     return module_impl;
})());
```

Comment: my question is why have `var module =` part. As you do `module_impl.prototype.xxx =` it will be accessible through `module` even without `var module =`  assignment...

Comment: No - `module` would not be defined, `module_impl` is local to the anonymous function and for the first time is the newly created object `{}`.

Comment: So without `module || {}` this `var module = ` have no sense?

Comment: without `module || {}` you will get and `undefined` error.

Comment: Above blog articles don't use `module || {}` in examples and call code as "augmentation". I afraid that authors give striped example so I have a question...